# How to make a variable by extracting specific line

Tags: r, matching

I have data like below

```
ABCB9  
rs11057374  
rs7138100  
rs11057375  
rs12309481  
END  

ABCC10  
rs1214748  
END  

ABCC2  
rs928578  
rs10883039  
END  

ABCC4  
rs12428035  
rs9561933  
rs9302086  
rs3848077  
rs3099362    
END
```

by using this data, I want to make the output like below

```
rs11057374  ABCB9  
rs7138100   ABCB9  
rs11057375  ABCB9  
rs12309481  ABCB9  



rs1214748  ABCC10   



rs928578    ABCC2    
rs10883039  ABCC2    



rs12428035  ABCC4    
rs9561933   ABCC4    
rs9302086   ABCC4    
rs3848077   ABCC4    
rs3099362   ABCC4
```

It is not necessary whether there are blank and "END"

How make the this output in R or linux?

Comment: oh sorry for misprint. i will edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We read the dataset with `readLines`, remove any trailing/leading spaces (`trimws`), remove the elements that are blank (`""`) or "END", create a grouping index ('i1') based on the occurrence of 'rs' as starting characters in the strings (based on the example provided), extract the first element of 'lines2' based on 'i1' ('nm1'), `split` the 'lines2' by 'i1', set the names of the `list` element with 'nm1', remove the first observation in each element of `list` and `stack` it to convert to a `data.frame`.

```
lines1 <- trimws(lines)
lines2 <- lines1[!lines1 %in% c("END", "")]
i1 <- cumsum(!grepl("^rs", lines2))
nm1 <- lines2[ave(i1,i1, FUN=seq_along)==1]
stack(setNames(lapply(split(lines2, i1), `[`, -1), nm1))
#     values    ind
#1  rs11057374  ABCB9
#2   rs7138100  ABCB9
#3  rs11057375  ABCB9
#4  rs12309481  ABCB9
#5   rs1214748 ABCC10
#6    rs928578  ABCC2
#7  rs10883039  ABCC2
#8  rs12428035  ABCC4
#9   rs9561933  ABCC4
#10  rs9302086  ABCC4
#11  rs3848077  ABCC4
#12  rs3099362  ABCC4
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("yourdata.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact, there were other type of variables in my data such as "c19_pos56113069" or "c2_pos113254071"
rather than rs number.  How I modify the "i1 <- cumsum(!grepl("^rs", lines2))
nm1 <- lines2[ave(i1,i1, FUN=seq_along)==1]" lines in this case?

Comment: @JChoi  I can only answer for the example you posted.  Do you have `ABC` common in that case?

Comment: @akrun2 I can't understand what ABC means. I will post with a much more detailed data. If possible, let me know in below URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617498/how-to-make-a-variable-by-extracting-specific-line