# How to make a variable by extracting specific line?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have data like below with SNP names (rs number or c#_pos#) included in gene names (e.g. ABCB9). In SNPs named as c#_pos000000, range of # is 1 to 22 (chromosome number)

```
ABCB9  
rs11057374  
rs7138100  
c22_pos41422393  
rs12309481  
END  

ABCC10  
rs1214748  
END  

HDAC9  
rs928578  
rs10883039  
END  

HCN2
rs12428035  
rs9561933  
c2_pos102345
rs3848077  
rs3099362    
END
```

by using this data, I want to make the output like below

```
rs11057374        ABCB9  
rs7138100         ABCB9  
c22_pos41422393   ABCB9  
rs12309481        ABCB9  

rs1214748         ABCC10   

rs928578          HDAC9    
rs10883039        HDAC9    

rs12428035        HCN2     
rs9561933         HCN2      
c2_pos102345      HCN2      
rs3848077         HCN2      
rs3099362         HCN2
```

It is not necessary whether there are blank and "END"

How make the this output in R or linux?

Comment: @akrun you're welcome, it's my pleasure and I thanks to your help.

Comment: Where is the data from, looks like MSigDB, could you provide a link?

Comment: @zx8754 the data is from output of geneset file(xxx.set) made by plink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this slightly differently.  After reading the file with `readLines` and removing the leading/lagging spaces (`trimws`), `split` the 'lines1' based on the grouping vector creating based on blank values (`""`), remove the `""` or `"END"` strings from the `list` elements, then set the `names` of the `list` with the first observation of each `list` element (`sapply(lst1,` [`, 1)`) while extracting all other elements except the first one and `stack` it.

```
lines1 <- trimws(lines)
lst1 <- lapply(split(lines1, cumsum(lines1=="")), 
                function(x) x[!x %in% c("", "END")])

stack(setNames(lapply(lst1,`[`,-1), sapply(lst1, `[`,1)))
#            values    ind
#1       rs11057374  ABCB9
#2        rs7138100  ABCB9
#3  c22_pos41422393  ABCB9
#4       rs12309481  ABCB9
#5        rs1214748 ABCC10
#6         rs928578  HDAC9
#7       rs10883039  HDAC9
#8       rs12428035   HCN2
#9        rs9561933   HCN2
#10    c2_pos102345   HCN2
#11       rs3848077   HCN2
#12       rs3099362   HCN2
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("yourdata.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than working from processed files, use raw files to get SNP Gene mapping. As you mentioned this data is output of [plink command](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/dataman.shtml#makeset) below:

```
plink --file mydata --make-set gene.list --write-set
```

So we already have *gene.list* and *mydata.map* files. Using those 2 files we can do below:

```
library(data.table)
# gene list file
geneList <- data.table(
  chr = 1:2,
  start = c(10, 40),
  end = c(13, 45),
  gene = paste0("gene_",1:2))
#    chr start end   gene
# 1:   1    10  13 gene_1
# 2:   2    40  45 gene_2

# map file
map <- data.table(
  chr = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3),
  snp = paste0("snp_",1:7),
  cm = 0,
  bp = c(10,11,15,40,41,49,100))

# prepare for merging, rename colnames to match gene list colnames
map <- map[, list(chr, start = bp, end = bp, snp)]
#    chr start end   snp
# 1:   1    10  10 snp_1
# 2:   1    11  11 snp_2
# 3:   1    15  15 snp_3
# 4:   2    40  40 snp_4
# 5:   2    41  41 snp_5
# 6:   2    49  49 snp_6
# 7:   3   100 100 snp_7

# set key for merging
setkey(map, chr, start, end)

# merge and susbset snp and gene columns
foverlaps(geneList, map)[, list(snp, gene)]
#      snp   gene
# 1: snp_1 gene_1
# 2: snp_2 gene_1
# 3: snp_4 gene_2
# 4: snp_5 gene_2
```

Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031) for more merge by overlap examples/functions.